# JQuery Autocomplete does not display array of countries

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a search box and an array of countries.

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/qBajXMw?editors=1111

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="country" v-model="search" class="form-control input-form" placeholder="Search Earth...">

var countries = {
"A2": "Andorra Test",
"AE": "United Arab Emirates",
"AF": "Afghanistan",
"AG": "Antigua and Barbuda",
"AI": "Anguilla" 
}
var countriesString = [
"Andorra",
"Andorra Test",
"Just another country",
"United Arab Emirates"
];
var countriesArray = $.map(countries, function (value, key) { return { value: value, data: key }; });

// Initialize ajax autocomplete:
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
// serviceUrl: '/autosuggest/service/url',
//lookup: countriesString,
lookup: countriesArray,
lookupFilter: function(suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
    var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
    return re.test(suggestion.value);
},
onSelect: function(suggestion) {
    $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
},
onHint: function (hint) {
    $('#autocomplete-ajax-x').val(hint);
},
onInvalidateSelection: function() {
    $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: none');
}
});
```

I loaded in the dependency libraries, JQuery and JQuery Autocomplete. The array of countries is not displaying properly.

Comment: Think it needs a `label` as well as a `value`.

Comment: Will take a look, thanks.